# Error : 'start' contains NA values when fitting frank copula

Tags: r, estimation

I am trying to fit a copula to some data in R and I get the error mentioned below.

```
library(copula)
data = matrix(data=runif(600),nrow=200,ncol=3)
data[,2] = 2*data[,1]
data[,3] = 3*data[,1]
fr_cop = frankCopula(dim=3)
fit_fr_cop = fitCopula(fr_cop,pobs(data),method = "mpl") #Error Here
```

The error message is as follows:

> Error in fitCopula.ml(copula, u = data, method = method, start = start,  :
> 'start' contains NA values

Comment: This seems more on topic for [SO] but wouldn't be accepted there because (a) you haven't indicated at what point the error is raised and (b) you haven't stripped this down to a minimal reproducible example.  I suspect we might be able to supply some insight here on CV, though, if you were to do both of those things.

Comment: what is the starting values for your parameters?

Comment: what is the parameter of Frank?